# Mechanize Timeouts

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm attempting to build a piece of code that searches for pages that timeout using Mechanize and Ruby. My test bed includes one page that is specifically written to timeout, and 3 pages that function normally. Here is the code:

```
urls = ['http://example.com/regular.php','http://example.com/regular2.php','http://example.com/regular3.php', 'http://example.com/tmeout.php']
m = Mechanize.new

urls.each do |url|
    begin
        status = Timeout::timeout(5.0) {
            m.get(url)
        }
   rescue Timeout::Error
       puts "TIMED OUT: " + url
   end
end
```

When the timeout URL is the **last** element in the list, this works perfectly fine. The `timeout` link prints to console. However, when the `timeout` link not the last element in the list (for ex, I place it first on the link), the `timeout` link prints to console however some of the `regular` links print to console too. This also appears to be non deterministic. Every time I rerun it, a different set of links will print to console.

Can anyone tell me why this is so and what fix is available? I've noticed that instantiated a new `mechanize` for each iteration solves the problem - however this is a non option because other parts of the program rely on the cookies from `m`, which would be reset if a new instance is created. Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google showed a few ideas. One was to try resetting `Mechanize` after a failure.

```
rescue Timeout::Error
   begin
    puts "TIMED OUT: " + url
    m = Mechanize.new
   end
```